# Node.JS: Cannot parse JSON file

Tags: node.js, json, file

**UPDATE**: Solved it. Turns out there was an undesired invisible first byte. Thank you all for your help! I removed it with `const xData = data.substr(1)`

---

Seems like an easy thing to do, and in fact it is, but I'm trying to parse a specific JSON file and I simply can't.

This JSON file is recognized by the system as an HTML file (according to the `file` command, due to it having massive amounts of HTML on it). I tried some online parsers, and they all say the JSON is fine.

Other files are recognized just fine.

Running on macOS Mojave, Node.JS 8.15.0, all files encoded in UTF-8.

Any clues on what to do here?

---

EDIT: JSON contents:

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "id": "24971",
        "title": " Funcionament d'un vehicle històric: L'Ou ja es mou",
        "image": "http://www.vilanova.cat/content/agenda/24971/LITTLEOU(2).JPG",
        "description": "<p>Circulació de l'Ou, una dresina d'obres de 194o. Aquesta activitat permet als visitants experimentar en tren per la nova via de contorn del Museu, des del baixador del Pont de Pineda fins al del Pont de Senyals, situats al passeig Entrevies.</p><p>Aquest vehicle construït el 1940, s'utilitzava per a facilitar els desplaçaments dels professionals del ferrocarril als diferents punts de les línies i poder fer les inspeccions o el manteniment de vies i el seguiment d'obres. És protagonista d'un conte de infantil de la col·lecció del Museu, titulat \"L'Ou que es mou\".</p>",
        "start_date": "20/01/2019",
        "end_date": "20/01/2019",
        "start_hour": "11:30",
        "end_hour": "13:30",
        "timetable": "<p> De les 11:30 a les 13:30</p>",
        "price": "Gratuït, inclós en qualsevol de les tarifes vigents d'emtrada al Museu",
        "location": "Museu del Ferrocarril de Catalunya. Vilanova i la Geltrú",
        "location_id": "1363",
        "address": "Plaça d'Eduard Maristany,     s/n",
        "x": "393725.02",
        "y": "4564273.16",
        "lon": "1.7310247183221",
        "lat": "41.2210496477307"
    }
]
}
```

Code:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const data = fs.readFileSync("./result.json", 'utf-8')
const json = JSON.parse(data)
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kyngo/Development/OpenDataImporter/reader.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Comment: It's most likely because your path is wrong, to a HTML 404 page is being returned, not the JSON response. Check the dev tools (sources), and let me know.

Comment: Without the file contents or your server code, I doubt anyone will be able to be of any help to you.

Comment: @Lissy path is not wrong, I triple checked it, data is okay.

Comment: @MadWard you're right, let me update this ASAP.

Comment: @Kyngo give details from the dev tools, so we can help you.

Comment: @Lissy it's server-side code, not web.

Comment: Ah okay. And you know that `./result.json` is expecting it to be in the route. If it's in the same directory you don't need the leading `./`

Comment: Also, when you log the result of `data`, before parse, what do you get?

Comment: @Lissy I'm aware of that, it's just old habits. Changing that doesn't affect the result.

Comment: Let's see the result of `data` then?

Comment: @Lissy it logs the JSON itself, let me post the error on the question.

Comment: Are you using `Content-Type:application/json` ?
Let's see the log of `data`

Comment: How am I supposed to use this when reading a local file? @Lissy

Comment: Well if your using `type json` you don't need to parse it, as it will be returned in JSON, not as JSON in a string

Comment: Please give exact log of `data` from your console. Include headers if u can

Comment: @Lissy I finally managed to fix that. You can see more details in the main question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice, well done. Add your solution as an answer below, then accept your own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this. The problem was a hidden char (first byte of the string), making the `JSON.parse()` method fail. What I did to bypass this is the following: `const xData = data.substr(1)`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trimming it like that. Instead, you should remove the extra byte form the file itself; workarounds like this which leave the byte intact will lead to more bugs later when other parts of your app don't account for that byte.

Comment: That's an option just as well. The result would be to save the contents of `xData` into that file, as I get it like that from its source, the which I don't have any control of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    import fs from 'fs';
    fs.readFile('./result.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const obj = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log('title', obj.data.title);
    });
```

Comment: ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/kyngo/Development/OpenDataImporter/reader.js:5:18
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)```